# Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking in global $U(1)$ symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I was reading SSB from **Ashok Das - Lectures on Quantum Field Theory**. I have a couple of questions.

> **First Question**

Equation **(7.65)** reads

$$\delta\sigma(x)=-i\epsilon[Q,\sigma(x)]=\epsilon\chi(x)$$
$$\delta\chi(x)=-i\epsilon[Q,\chi(x)]=-\epsilon\sigma(x)$$

But I get a different relation,

$$\delta\sigma(x)=i\epsilon[Q,\sigma(x)]=\epsilon\chi(x)$$
$$\delta\chi(x)=i\epsilon[Q,\chi(x)]=-\epsilon\sigma(x)$$

I don't get the "-" before the commutators. So which relation is correct?

> **Second Question**

While deriving $H|\chi\rangle=E_0|\chi\rangle$ in equation **(7.70)**, why does $H|0\rangle=E_0|0\rangle$? Shouldn't $H|0\rangle = 0$, like we normally expect.

> **Third Question**

In equation **(7.71)** while showing that $\langle\chi|\chi\rangle\rightarrow\infty$, the author plugs in

$$\langle\chi|\chi\rangle=\int d^3x\langle0|e^{iP\cdot x}J^0(0)e^{-iP\cdot x}Q|0\rangle$$

From where does the author plug in, $e^{-iP\cdot x}$ and $e^{iP\cdot x}$?

Comment: **1)** no idea, I don't own that book (you should make the question self-contained and post the relevant equations) **2)** $H|0\rangle=E_0|0\rangle$ is more general than $H|0\rangle=0$. The latter takes $E_0=0$ which defined the origin of energies, while the former does not. **3)** the author is just using $\phi(x)=e^{-iPx}\phi(0)e^{+iPx}$ which is valid for any operator (because $e^{iPx}$ is the translation operator). In this case, $\phi(x)=J(x)$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: You can always search in Google Books. You will get a positive hit.

Comment: Note that one should only ask one question per post, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451) meta post.